# Return HTTP response in Python lambda which performs multiple DynamoDB put items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda which performs multiple dynamodb puts. This is the handler

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ddbclient = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'xxx}})
    ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'yyy}})
    ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'zzz}})
    ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'aaa}})
    ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'bbb}})
```

Now I'm looking for the correct way to return an HTTP response.
Do I have to check every reponse like this and check if they are all statuscode 200?:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ddbclient = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    resp1 = ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'xxx}})
    resp2 = ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'yyy}})
    resp3 = ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'zzz}})
    resp4 = ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'aaa}})
    resp5 = ddbclient.put_item(TableName='Tacticalble', Item={'bbb}})
```

What is the correct way to return a HTTP200 when all put's succeed and return an error code when one of the put fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [DynamoDB transactions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.transact_write_items) instead of multiple put requests
2. In case of error Exception would be raised. See [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html)